# How to extract specific information from a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I work in the racing industry and get vast amounts of race data I have to sort through daily.  It all comes in one cell, and I must extract parts into separate cells.  The data I'm having trouble with is the Race Diatnance and the Race Type.  I've attached a photo with a few example races.  I've highlighted the Distance in yellow, and the Race Type in blue.   I can't work out a formula to place the Race Distance in one cell, and another that gets the Race Type into another.

I've managed to use LEFT and RIGHT to extract the Race Start Time, Course and Horse Name, but I can't work out what to use for the other two.
[Example of Data Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McV0d.png)

Comment: How would I use Regex to get the Race Course from the data set?  Race Course is always between the time and the Date at the start.  Some Course's names are 3-4 words, not just a single word like in the example image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\\(.+?) (.+?)\\")
```